# Convert 1 column in df to key and another to values to form a dictionary

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, pandas

I have
df:

```
ClientName   ID             ID2         RoomTypeName    RoomDescription
Emerson     3609           NCGY           STANDARD            A2T
Morningstar 3667           ND8Q           STANDARD        C1D,B1Q,B1K
Morningstar 3668           ND8Q           STANDARD        C1Q,B1Q,B2T
Morningstar 3748           ND8Q           STANDARD          B1Q,STU
Morningstar 3748           ND8Q            DELUXE           SQ1,SK1
McDonalds   3773            NI0           STANDARD            STD
McDonalds   3773            NI0            DELUXE             DLC
```

I want the final result to be grouped by clientname, ID and ID2 and have a mapping or a dictionary in place that creates a key value pair for roomtypename and roomdescription
so for ex: if I search for id 3748's deluxe roomtype it should spit out SQ1,SK1. How can I achieve this?
Desired output
df:

```
ClientName   ID             ID2         RoomTypeName    RoomDescription
Emerson     3609           NCGY           STANDARD            [A2T]
Morningstar 3667           ND8Q           STANDARD        [C1D,B1Q,B1K]
Morningstar 3668           ND8Q           STANDARD        [C1Q,B1Q,B2T]
Morningstar 3748           ND8Q       STANDARD,DELUXE   [B1Q,STU][SQ1,SK1]
McDonalds   3773            NI0       STANDARD,DELUXE      [STD],[DLC]
```

Comment: Hi Tarik. Thanks for editing my question. I am fairly new to stack overflow, Can you please tell me how you managed to change that messy table into a df? Thanks

Comment: Just add 4 white spaces before each line.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than creating a dictionary, just change the DataFrame index to have ID and RoomTypeName as keys:

```
df = df.set_index(['ID', 'RoomTypeName'])
result = df.loc[('3748', 'DELUXE')]
```

Comment: I want both standard and deluxe of each ID to be in 1 line, because I need to run a for loop for each row immediately after

Comment: Then use the ID only as an index and grab both rows in the loop by doing the loc twice, one for the deluxe and one for standard.

Comment: If you tell me what you are trying to achieve, we may find a better solution. The whole idea of using DataFrames is to vectorize code. Looping defeats the purpose and you may just fall back on using native Python data structures.

Comment: Sure, This is a part of an automation of sending email alerts. The original df is the data I get. In the email for each id, I need to write out all the roomdescriptions for standard and deluxe separately. for ex: for 3748: STD:  B1Q,STU and DLX: SQ1,SK1

Comment: Ok, then the proposed solution should do. Try it out.

Comment: Ok, will do. Thanks for the advise.

Comment: Mark question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

```
df = yourdf.groupby(['ClientName', 'ID', 'ID2'])
```

when you do this your dataframe will get changed, like the values which are grouped will be in a single cell as list elements, now creating a dictionary out of it is a tricky job, it is dynamic. which means that you'll be having the key as an array in your dictionary. when you groupby the `clientName` some of your `ID` column values become lists. and if you create a dictionary with `ID` and `RoomDescription` you don't get the result you're expecting.